# Скачивание по ссылке с google drive на PHP

Tags: php, google-drive

Как без API вытянуть файлы используя PHP и записать на локалку?
Вот ссылки различных видов.

1. https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1v-iJOyt-G_8YuspPzSPXFHlkJtiIt2v_
2. https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1v-iJOyt-G_8YuspPzSPXFHlkJtiIt2v_

Answer (score 0):

Нагуглил:
С помощью функции PHP file_get_contents() и file_put_contents():

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com.ua/logos/doodles/2016/earth-day-2016-5741289212477440.4-5728116278296576-ror.jpg';
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/my-img.jpg';
file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($url));
```

Пример с использованием с cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.google.com.ua/logos/doodles/2016/earth-day-2016-5741289212477440.4-5728116278296576-ror.jpg');
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/my-img.jpg', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Ссылка на оригинал: [Тут](https://xn--d1acnqm.xn--j1amh/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8/php-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-url)